# class Zend/Db not found,i need to display my album table data in zendpdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

```
$db = Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT Name, Code, Region FROM album LIMIT 0, 150');
```

Comment: check your include path i suppose class name is wrong

Comment: use zend/db; I include too but its showing error???any example

Comment: just check the class name inside zend library db.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

this is the correct class name

```
Db.php is the file name but the class is Zend_Db
```